# QGIS Flow accumulation tool frozen at 100%

Tags: qgis, raster, saga, flow-accumulation, topographic-wetness-index

My goal is to apply a topographic wetness index to a DEM using QGIS Version 3.20.2-Odense, running on a macOS laptop. I have clipped my DEM layer for the appropriate study area, and calculated slope for the study area using Raster Analysis. I am now trying to calculate the upstream contributing area for the study area using the SAGA Flow accumulation (qm of esp) processing tool. However, no matter how long I leave this final step running, the algorithm never progresses past 100%, and the program stops responding, and I have to either cancel it or shut it down without running the Flow accumulation successfully.

I am completely new to QGIS but need to use it for a hydrology research paper in my studies.

Comment: Try other Flow Accumulation tools (please have a look at a comment by the SAGA team about how [qm of esp](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/354013/thread/e9f28d35/) is designed).